# Simple Form For - Rails - f.association options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have the following field in my form:

```
<%= f.association :account_manager, collection: Person.appear_on_register_page, :value_method => :id, :label_method => :full_name, :required => true, prompt: "Please Select", label: label %>
```

This gives the user a textbox, which when clicked on gives a dropdown with every record in the collection. When typing in the text box, this dropdown is narrowed to only match what is in the text box.

I've been asked to remove the dropdown until a user has started entering text - for example when first clicking on the text box no drop down appears until the first 3 letters have been entered - then all records matching those three letters appear.

I've looked through their github and can't find any options for this.. Any help is appreciated

Comment: What do you use for that dropdown with typing ? Selectize ?

Comment: After much searching it was jquery handling this, thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you are looking for a auto complete text box. You can achieve this using Jquery UI.

This is a good [gem](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) you can go with.

This is one of the good [tutorial](http://lugolabs.com/articles/20-jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-ruby-on-rails) for that. Thanks

Comment: +1 for pointing me in the right direction - jquery is handling this so was looking in the wrong place - thanks!